# Get initial month from list of dates

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset of two variables: **DATE** and **Years of service** for an individual (only used to make a small reproducible example).
I need to obtain the month in which this person begins to work, (for this example is in 1989-06) taking into account that the month in which it started may vary from individuals if the solution applies to many.
Something like this:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- structure(list(DATE = c("2009-01", "2009-02", "2009-03", "2009-04", 
                          "2009-05", "2009-06", "2009-07", "2009-08", "2009-09", "2009-10", 
                          "2009-11", "2009-12", "2010-01", "2010-02", "2010-03", "2010-04", 
                          "2010-05", "2010-06", "2010-07", "2010-08", "2010-09", "2010-10", 
                          "2010-11", "2010-12", "2011-01", "2011-02", "2011-03", "2011-04", 
                          "2011-05", "2011-06", "2011-07", "2011-08", "2011-09", "2011-10", 
                          "2011-11", "2011-12"), Years_service = c(19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
                                                                   20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
                                                                   21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22), 
                 INITIAL_MONTH = c("1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", 
                                   "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", 
                                   "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", 
                                   "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", 
                                   "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", 
                                   "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", 
                                   "1989-06", "1989-06")), .Names = c("DATE", "Years_service", 
                                                                      "INITIAL_MONTH"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,-36L))

head(dt)
      DATE Years_service INITIAL_MONTH
1: 2009-01            19       1989-06
2: 2009-02            19       1989-06
3: 2009-03            19       1989-06
4: 2009-04            19       1989-06
5: 2009-05            19       1989-06
6: 2009-06            20       1989-06
```

How can I get it in R?

Comment: Is column `INITIAL_MONTH` your expected output? How are you calculating it based on `Date`  and `Years_service` ? How are you getting output `1989-06` for all?

Comment: Yes, that column is my expected output. I calculate that column by subtracting Date - Years of service.

Comment: For the 1st row, assuming `2009-01` is year and month if you subtract 19 years from it shouldn't you get `1990-01` ?

Comment: Yes but as you can see in column Years_service it changes when has the value of june, I need that the INITIAL MONTH will be unique, that´s why I repeat this value. It is the unique date in which the individual starts to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could find the first change in `Years_service` column and subtract it with corresponding `DATE` value present at that index.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

dt %>%
  mutate(inds = which.max(diff(Years_service) != 0) + 1, 
        init_month = format(as.Date(paste0(DATE[inds], "-01")) - 
                      years(Years_service[inds]), "%Y-%m")) %>%
  select(-inds)

#      DATE Years_service INITIAL_MONTH init_month
#1  2009-01            19       1989-06    1989-06
#2  2009-02            19       1989-06    1989-06
#3  2009-03            19       1989-06    1989-06
#4  2009-04            19       1989-06    1989-06
#....
```

You might want to do this for multiple persons you can add `group_by` clause to it

```
dt %>%
  group_by(person) %>%
  mutate(inds = which.max(diff(Years_service) != 0) + 1, 
         init_month = format(as.Date(paste0(DATE[inds], "-01")) - 
                       years(Years_service[inds]), "%Y-%m")) %>%
  select(-inds)
```

---

**EDIT**

For the updated case , we may need to `arrange` the `dates` first

```
dt1 <- dt[order(-DATE)]

dt1 %>%
  mutate(dates = as.Date(paste0(DATE, "-01"))) %>%
  arrange(dates) %>%
  mutate(inds = which.max(diff(Years_service) != 0) + 1, 
     init_month = format(dates[inds] - years(Years_service[inds]), "%Y-%m")) %>%
  select(-inds)
```

Comment: Is it possible to give a solution that is not dependent on the order of data?

Comment: @Israel what do you mean by order of data?

Comment: Yes, order of data.

Comment: Because if I change order of data, your solution changes too

Comment: How ? Can you show me with an example where it fails? It is difficult to provide a solution without a reproducible example.

Comment: it is:    dt1 <- dt[order(-DATE)]
     dt1 %>%
          mutate(inds = which.max(diff(Years_service) != 0) + 1, 
             init_month = format(as.Date(paste0(DATE[inds], "-01")) - 
                                   years(Years_service[inds]), "%Y-%m")) %>%
      select(-inds)

Comment: @Israel I see your point now. Thank you for providing an example..I have updated my answer. (See the EDIT part). Let me know if it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution

Use `seq` to count back by the amount of months

1. Create a new `Date` vector with day (`%d`) (to please the `as.Date` function) using `sprintf`

```
dt$Date <- sprintf("%s-01",dt$DATE)
```

2. Create a vector of strings of the format `-X months` to count backwards with in `seq`

```
dt$Back_step <- sprintf("-%s months",dt$Years_service)
```

3. Use a `for` loop to cycle through the rows printing the date X months before

```
for(i in 1:nrow(dt)){
  dt$INITIAL_MONTH[i] <- as.character(seq(as.Date(dt$Date[i],format="%Y-%m-%d"), 
                                                  length = 2, by = dt$Back_step[i])[2])
}
```

N.B. The `[2]` shows that we are taking the second value in the sequence

Answer (score 0):

Add a data.table solution as well.

```
# Find the initial month
dt1 <- dt[order(DATE)]
dt1[, diff:=Years_service - shift(Years_service)]
dt2 <- dt1[diff==1, head(.SD, 1)]
# calculate the year
dt2[, init_month:=paste0(as.numeric(substr(DATE, 1, 4))-Years_service, '-', substr(DATE, 6, 7))]
# write back to the original data.table
init_mon <- dt2$init_month[1]
dt <- dt[, init_month:=init_mon]
```

If there are multiple persons in the data:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- structure(list(PERSON = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
                                2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
                                2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                     DATE = c("2009-01", "2009-02", "2009-03", "2009-04", 
                          "2009-05", "2009-06", "2009-07", "2009-08", "2009-09", "2009-10", 
                          "2009-11", "2009-12", "2010-01", "2010-02", "2010-03", "2010-04", 
                          "2010-05", "2010-06", "2010-07", "2010-08", "2010-09", "2010-10", 
                          "2010-11", "2010-12", "2011-01", "2011-02", "2011-03", "2011-04", 
                          "2011-05", "2011-06", "2011-07", "2011-08", "2011-09", "2011-10", 
                          "2011-11", "2011-12", "2009-01", "2009-02", "2009-03", "2009-04", 
                          "2009-05", "2009-06", "2009-07", "2009-08", "2009-09", "2009-10", 
                          "2009-11", "2009-12", "2010-01", "2010-02", "2010-03", "2010-04", 
                          "2010-05", "2010-06", "2010-07", "2010-08", "2010-09", "2010-10", 
                          "2010-11", "2010-12", "2011-01", "2011-02", "2011-03", "2011-04", 
                          "2011-05", "2011-06", "2011-07", "2011-08", "2011-09", "2011-10", 
                          "2011-11", "2011-12"), Years_service = c(19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
                                                                   20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
                                                                   21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
                                                                   20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
                                                                   21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22), 
                 INITIAL_MONTH = c("1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", 
                                   "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", 
                                   "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", 
                                   "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", 
                                   "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", 
                                   "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", 
                                   "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", 
                                   "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", 
                                   "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", 
                                   "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", 
                                   "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", 
                                   "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", "1989-06", 
                                   "1989-06", "1989-06")), .Names = c("PERSON", "DATE", "Years_service", 
                                                                      "INITIAL_MONTH"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,-36L))


head(dt)

# PERSON    DATE    Years_service   INITIAL_MONTH
# 1         2009-01 19              1989-06
# 1         2009-02 19              1989-06
# 1         2009-03 19              1989-06
# 1         2009-04 19              1989-06
# 1         2009-05 19              1989-06
# 1         2009-06 20              1989-06
```

Add group by in the calculation

```
dt1 <- dt[order(PERSON, DATE)]
dt1[, diff:=Years_service - shift(Years_service), by="PERSON"]
dt2 <- dt1[diff==1, head(.SD, 1), by="PERSON"]
dt2[, init_month:=paste0(as.numeric(substr(DATE, 1, 4))-Years_service, '-', substr(DATE, 6, 7))]
dt <- merge(dt, dt2[, list(PERSON, init_month)], on=c("PERSON"), all.x=TRUE)
```

Comment: Your solution it's nice but I want a solution that will not be dependent on the order of data